# $this->assertEquals error : Failed asserting that null matches expected

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I'm doing test unit of my entity:

```php
namespace PathtomyBundle\Tests;

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/../../../app/AppKernel.php';

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;

abstract class TestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
/**
 * @var Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\AppKernel
 */
protected $kernel;

/**
 * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
 */
protected $entityManager;

/**
 * @var Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container
 */
protected $container;

public function setUp()
{
    // Boot the AppKernel in the test environment and with the debug.
    $this->kernel = new \AppKernel('test', true);
    $this->kernel->boot();

    // Store the container and the entity manager in test case properties
    $this->container = $this->kernel->getContainer();
    $this->entityManager = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

    // Build the schema for sqlite
    //$this->generateSchema();

    parent::setUp();
}

public function tearDown()
{
    // Shutdown the kernel.
    $this->kernel->shutdown();

    parent::tearDown();
}

protected function generateSchema()
{
    // Get the metadatas of the application to create the schema.
    $metadatas = $this->getMetadatas();

    if ( ! empty($metadatas)) {
        // Create SchemaTool
        $tool = new SchemaTool($this->entityManager);
        $tool->createSchema($metadatas);
    } else {
        throw new Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException('No Metadata Classes to process.');
    }
}

/**
 * Overwrite this method to get specific metadatas.
 *
 * @return Array
 */
protected function getMetadatas()
{
    return $this->entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
}
}
```

and also:

```php
 namespace pathtomybundle\Tests\Entity;
 use pathtomybundle\Tests\TestCase;
 use pathtomybundle\Entity\Calendars;

 require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/TestCase.php';

 class CalendarsDbTest extends TestCase
 {

protected $Calendars;

    public function setUp()
        {
            parent::setUp();

            $this->Calendars = new Calendars();
        }


    public function testGenerateCalendars()
    {

        $this->Calendars->setBeginDate(new \DateTime('now'));
        $this->Calendars->setDescription('Description');
        $this->Calendars->setEndDate(new \DateTime('now'));
        $this->Calendars->setType('sur titre');

        // Save the ExCalendars
        $this->entityManager->persist($this->Calendars);
        $this->entityManager->flush();



    }

       public function testUser(){

     $this->assertEquals('Description', $this->Calendars->getDescription() );

    }
```

So my questions are:

- Why does it raise this error "Failed asserting that null matches expected"?
- Why `getDescription()` returns `NULL`?
- How to test two table with One-to-Many relationship for example my Table Calendars with another table in database?

**Edit**

For the third question :

For example I have two Tables Job and Calenders with Many-to-One relationship so I will have a Job_Id field in Calendars Table,so how I will do my test Unit with a foreign key "job_id"

In Calendars Entity :

```
 /**
 * @var Job
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Job")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="job_id", referencedColumnName="job_id")
 * })
 */
private $jobId;
```

**Edit-2-**

when I run my phpunit test "phpunit -c app" to test setters function and persist in database so I have a  with every test a new data insered in databse, my question is it possible to do a lot of test but  I insert data in database just for one time because actually I must remove data from database with every test.

2 - another question : to create a database_test i use "$this->generateSchema();
" so after create a database for the first time and when the test call "TestCase"class (the code above) again so he tried to create the database_test again then I must remove the line after the first time and it's not good,so what I can do to run this line just for one time in the first time when i run my test?

**Edit-3**

```
    /**
 * @var Job
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Job")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="job_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $job;
```

it's normal?

Comment: The first question: Because every test get there own scope, another test cannot affect something for the other tests.

Comment: Please if u answer so with code and proof,like that you deprive the other member to answer me correctly,please you must be more respectful...

Comment: what did I wrong? I don't know to answer to all 3 questions and I wasn't sure about my answer of the 1st question. That is exactly why Stackoverflow invented comments: if you want to share your opinion/ideas with the rest of the world but you cannot give a correct answer to the question or aren't sure about your answer.

Comment: Please split out the third question into a new question. It is completely unrelated to the first two.

Comment: @DavidHarkness you can look my edit in my first message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Every test in test case creates his own CalendarsDbTest object. So, in fact, $this->Calendar is different object in each test (if you want share it between tests you need create it in setUp method)
2. Is the same as above (there is null because you never call setDescription with $this->Calendars - it's different object than it is in first test)
3. I'm not sure what exactly you mean. Can you show more precise (for example method you want test) what you mean?

**edit:**

The answer is: you don't test it. Why? Because unit test is UNIT test - you should test here only your entity. Persistence, keeping relations etc. are Doctrine resposibility and should be tested there - you don't worry about it.

The only thing you should test is setter/getter for $jobId property (btw. it should be "$job" rather than "$jobId" because it's object of Job class - not an integer), eg.:

```
class CalendarTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
     (...)

     public function testSetGetJob()
     {
         $job = new Job();
         $job->setSomeProperty('someValue');  

         $expectedJob = clone $job; // you clone this because in setter you pass object by reference  

         $calendar = new Calendar();
         $calendar->setJob($job);

         $this->assertEquals($expectedJob, $calendar->getJob());
     }

     (...)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand very well your code,can you explain me more your code using "JobTest" and "CalendarsTest" classes...And also I have another question you can see my Edit in my frist message

Comment: Ok. In Calendars entity probably you have methods like setJob and getJob and you want test them. So my code is testing both - setter and getter for $job property (this is example for CalendarsTest). 1) you build sample $job object and you use it with $calendar->setJob() method. 2) you build Job object $expectedJob which should be returned with $calendar->getJob(). In our case it's the same object as we use in setJob method (because it was simple setter). 3) You check wheter object returned by $calendar->getJob is the same as $expectedJob. If yes - then everything went ok and test passed.

Comment: If you still don't understand please clarify which part is unclear for you.

Comment: Yes I understand but Im talking about "$JobId" not "$Job" so why you give me an example with "setJob and getJob" not with "setJobId and getJobId"??

Comment: Oh. It's only because property should name "$job" (not $jobId) because it's not an integer but an object of class Job. And therefore setter and getter should be named setJob and getJob. (of course if you stay with name $jobId setter and getter will be setJobId and getJobId)

Comment: In the same i guess u are true because when i generate automaticly my entity,it's give me in entity Calenders Class ==> see my adit 3 code above...

Comment: Exactly. It's correct. Because on ORM level you create relations between entities, so property should contain object of related entity (in our example it's $job property which will be an instance of Job class). And ORM retrieves these relation based on job_id field in database (you specify this field in @Joincolumn annotation).

Comment: ok Cyprian but  value of $expectedJob = clone $job; will be string or int?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16282/discussion-between-cyprian-and-nll)